# Реализация итерационного метода

Tags: java

При выполнении работы в которой необходимо бюло реализовать метод Ньютона, для нахождения нулей функции, возникла проблема. Компилятор не заходит в метод SOLVE класса Solve_NewthonMethod. Код представлен ниже:

```
package ItMethods;
import  ItMethods.Function;

public class Solve_NewthonMethod {
    double Approx;
    double E,x,stop;
    boolean b1,b2,b3,b4;
    double tmp,res;

    Function f= new Function(5, 1.8,2.3);


    // Выбор начального приближения:
    Solve_NewthonMethod(double E) {
       // Approx = A;
        this.E = E;
        for (double i = f.a; i <= f.b; i += this.E) {
            if (f.DiffFun1(i) > 0 && f.DiffFun2(i) > 0 || f.DiffFun1(i) < 0 && f.DiffFun2(i) < 0) { //
                Approx = f.b;
            } else Approx = f.a;
        }
    }

        // ДОСТАТОЧНЫЕ УСЛОВИЯ
        // 1е достаточное условие: f(a)*f(b)<0
      boolean CheckFun(){
        if(f.getFun(f.a)*f.getFun(f.b)<0){
            System.out.println("Уравнение точно имеет хотя бы один корень.");
            b1=true;
        }
        return b1;
    }

        // 2e достаточное условие: x0 должно удовлетворять f(x0)*f``(x0)>0
    boolean CheckInApprox() {
        if (f.getFun(Approx) * f.DiffFun2(Approx) > 0) {
            System.out.println("Верное приближение");
            return b2 = true;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Начальное приближнение не удовлетворяет условию f`(x0)*f``(x0)>0.");
            return false;
        }
    }

        //3е достаточное условие: 1я Производная не должна = 0 и должна сохр знак для всех х из промежутка от а до b. В качестве шага взята точность.
      boolean CheckDiff(){
          for(double i=f.a;i<=f.b;i+=this.E){
          if(f.DiffFun1(i)!=0 && (f.DiffFun1(i)>0 || f.DiffFun1(i)<0)){
              b3=true;
          }
      }
         return b3;
      }
        //4е достаточное условие: 2я Производная должна сохранять знак на всем интервале
    boolean CheckDiff1() {
        for (double i = f.a; i <= f.b; i += this.E) {
            if (f.DiffFun2(i) > 0 || f.DiffFun2(i) < 0) {
                b4 = true;
            }
        }
        return b4;
    }

    **void Solve(){
          if(b1 && b2 && b3 && b4  ) {
              do {
                  x = Approx - f.getFun(Approx) / f.DiffFun1(Approx);
                  stop=x-Approx;
                  Approx=x;
                  System.out.println(+x);
              } while (Math.abs(stop) > E );
          //    if (x > f.a && x < f.b) {
          //        System.out.println(+x);
          //    } else System.out.println("Нет корней на данном интервале.");
          }
         // System.out.println("Не выполненно одно из достаточных условий!");
    }**

}
```

Класс функции (знаю,что все не оч,но я только начинаю вникать в прогу,поэтому извиняюсь):

```
package ItMethods;
import  ItMethods.Solve_NewthonMethod;
public class Function {

    int Pow;
    double a, b, temp;
    private int counter;

    /*
     *       КОНСТРУКТОР
     */


    Function(int Pow, double a, double b) {
        if (Pow >= 10 || Pow < 2) return;
        this.Pow = Pow;
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;

        //Замечания:

            if (Pow % 2 == 1) System.out.println("Так как старшая степень полинома равна " + Pow + " ,то следует,что полином \n имеет хотя-бы один действительный корень. ");

        if (a > b) {
            temp = b;
            b = a;
            a = temp;
        }
        System.out.println("Интервал: ["+a+";"+b+"]");

    }

    public double getFun(double InApprox){ 
        return Math.pow(InApprox,Pow)-3*Math.pow(InApprox,Pow-2)-4*Math.pow(InApprox,Pow-3)-2*InApprox+4;
    }

    public double DiffFun1(double InApprox){ 
        return  Pow*Math.pow(InApprox,Pow-1)-3*(Pow-2)*Math.pow(InApprox,Pow-3)-4*(Pow-3)*Math.pow(InApprox,Pow-4)-2;
    }

    public double DiffFun2(double InApprox){
        return  Pow*(Pow-1)*Math.pow(InApprox,Pow-2)-3*(Pow-2)*(Pow-3)*Math.pow(InApprox,Pow-4)-4*(Pow-3)*(Pow-4)*Math.pow(InApprox,Pow-5);
    }
}
```

И,наконец-таки,класс для теста:

```
package ItMethods;
import ItMethods.Solve_NewthonMethod;
import ItMethods.Solve_HalfDiv;
public class TestMethod {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Solve_NewthonMethod a= new Solve_NewthonMethod(0.01);
        a.Solve(); // НЕ ВЫВОДИТ
        System.out.println(a.CheckDiff()+" "+a.CheckFun()+" "+a.CheckInApprox()+" "+a.CheckDiff1());
        //System.out.println(a.Approx);


      
    }
}
```

Помогите,пожалуйста,разобраться в чем дело. Огромное спасибо за ваше внимание и потраченное время для ответа на данный вопрос!

Comment: По коду: очень важно соблюдать правила именования. Классы с большой буквы, без подчёркиваний, методы и переменные - с маленькой буквы. Если это правила не соблюдать - код становится слабо читаемым. По вопросу - компилятор тут не причём. Скорее всего у вас во время исполнения просто не выполняется условие внутри метода (то или иное), вот вы и не видите вывода в логи. Если перед условием вывести в логи значения переменных из условия - многое может проясниться. Скорее всего какие-то у вас ошибки в логике в коде.

Comment: Добрый вечер! Спасибо, я учту замечание на счет читабельности и буду исправляться. Попробую подумать над логикой и перепроверить результаты

Answer (score 0):

Методы `CheckDiff`, `CheckFun`, `CheckInApprox`, `CheckDiff1` сохраняют результаты проверок в соответствующие переменные `b1`, `b2`, `b3`, `b4`. Метод `Solve` в свою очередь производит проверку этих переменных и должен быть  выполнен после выполнения методов `CheckDiff`, `CheckFun`, `CheckInApprox`, `CheckDiff1`.

```
package ItMethods;

public class TestMethod {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Solve_NewthonMethod a =
                new Solve_NewthonMethod(0.01);
        a.CheckDiff();
        a.CheckFun();
        a.CheckInApprox();
        a.CheckDiff1();
        a.Solve();
    }

}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!